# Install cassandra datastax enterprise version with yum: how to set username & password

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to install cassandra datastax enterprise version on a EC2 cluster with Amazon Linux OS. I'm following the installation instruction here to install it by yum:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installRHELdse.html

It asks me to enter a proper url like below with my username and password included into the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/datastax.repo`:

```
baseurl=https://dsa_email_address:password@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise
```

Now say my email address is my@email.com, and password is my?password (including a question mark). I tried to set the url as:

```
https://my@email.com:my?password@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise
```

Then I run `yum update -y`, it generates the following error message:

```
[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 51 - "Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate."
Trying other mirror.
```

Now if I escape `@` to `%40` in my email address as instructed, which is:

```
https://my%40email.com:my?password@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise
```

I get the error:

```
[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Could not resolve host: my%40email.com"
Trying other mirror.
```

I've also tried to escape `?` with `\?`, it doesn't make any differences. I've also double checked I'm able to login to datastax website with the email and password combination. So how should I set my email and password to download and install it in yum? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

OK I just found how to fix it myself. I need to quote the url with `""`, and escape `@` with `%40`. Also, I changed my password to remove the question mark, because ? is certainly not a friendly character in an url. So now the url is like:

```
baseurl="https://my%40email.com:mypassword@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise"
```

Comment: Thanks. Note for everyone else... the docs state to replace the `@` in the email address only, I was doing it in the host section also, Doh!